# iron-list multi-selection adds items multiple times to selection

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a `multi-selection`-enabled `iron-list` and my problem is that instead of selecting/deselecting items when clicking, the clicked element of `[[children]]` is added to the `{{selectedChildren}}`, once per click.

```
<iron-list items="[[children]]" selected-items="{{selectedChildren}}" selection-enabled multi-selection>
    <template>
        <div class$="[[iconForItem(selected, item)]]">
            <iron-image class="avatar" sizing="contain" src="[[item.pic]]"></iron-image>
            <div class="pad">
                <div class="primary" th:inline="none">[[item.name]]</div>
                <div class="secondary dim" th:inline="none">[[item.bdate]]</div>
                <div><paper-textarea value="{{item.comment}}" on-tap="noFoc"></paper-textarea></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-list>
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: I think there is more information needed also a working fiddle would be nice. Please clarify what it is doing and what you think it should do.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was:

```
properties: {
    selectedChildren: {
        type: Array, // bad idea
        value: []    // bad idea
    }
}
```

It should be:

```
properties: {
    selectedChildren: {
        type: Object // This works
    }
}
```